# Checking cache using ADD command with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, http, dockerfile, bitbucket, docker-run

I think it's the http headers that are being sent by Bitbucket. I have this in a Dockerfile:

```
ADD https://bitbucket.org/teros/datavana/raw/"$commit"/moodwire/mwapi/requirements.txt  '/teros/temp/requirements.txt'
ADD https://bitbucket.org/teros/datavana/raw/"$commit"/moodwire/mwapi/constraints.txt '/teros/temp/constraints.txt'
```

but the problem is those files haven't changed, but Docker doesn't cache them - it re-runs them:

```
Step 32/63 : ARG commit
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a60e2b6be500
Step 33/63 : ADD https://bitbucket.org/teros/datavana/raw/"$commit"/moodwire/mwapi/requirements.txt  '/teros/temp/requirements.txt'
Downloading  1.545kB
 ---> 2e3b379a1ac4
Step 34/63 : ADD https://bitbucket.org/teros/datavana/raw/"$commit"/moodwire/mwapi/constraints.txt '/teros/temp/constraints.txt'
Downloading  1.545kB
```

is because Bitbucket is not responding with an HTTP 300 code? Maybe there is a query param I can use something like:

```
https://bitbucket.org/teros/datavana/raw/"$commit"/moodwire/mwapi/constraints.txt?use_cache=yes
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Docker is looking at the `Last-Modified` header to determine caching behavior.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add